# Trying to load params through webViewClient but getting error from mnemonics not defined

Tags: android

Here is my code and it's working in demo project but not in my project. I am trying to add these parameters through webView Client but it is showing from mnemonics not found.

```
fun sendTrx(c:Context, from_address: String, fromMnemonics: String, amount: String, toAddress: String) {
    mycontext=c
    var webvw = WebView(mycontext)
    webvw.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android")
    webvw.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webvw.settings.domStorageEnabled=true
    webvw.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
        ): Boolean {
            getCustomHeaders()?.let { view!!.loadUrl(request!!.url.toString(), it) };
            return true;
        }

    }
    webvw.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/send.html")
    val amtChanged = amount.toDouble() * 1000000000000
    val amtTobeTransferred = BigDecimal(amtChanged).toBigInteger()
    webvw.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)


            webvw.loadUrl("javascript:from_address(\"$from_address\")")
            webvw.loadUrl("javascript:fromMnemonics(\"$fromMnemonics\")")
            webvw.loadUrl("javascript:amtTobeTransferred(\"$$amtTobeTransferred\")")
            webvw.loadUrl("javascript:toAddress(\"$toAddress\")")
        //    webvw.loadUrl("javascript:toAddress(\"$toAddress\")")
           



        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check in your javascript code that you have field/ method named "fromMnemonics" or not

Comment: yes i have and when i am debugging it is also showing and same code is working in demo project but not in my project